# KnockOut understanding ko.computed function last "this" reference in return statement

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to understand what the use of the last `this` in the following tutorial example

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    },this);//This one!
}
```

I understand that the other `this`'s pertain to the `AppViewModel()` being constructed and when I remove the comma and last `this` the example doesn't bind any data.  With the `this.fullName` wouldn't that be sufficient to bind that function to the `AppViewModel()`?

So as it stands the `ko.computed(function()...` is saying return the references within this object to `firstName` and `lastName` concatenated set to this instances `fullName`, what piece am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the assignment of the computed to `this.fullName`; it has to do with the value of `this` inside the computed function. By default, the `this` in `return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();` when evaluated in the context of the computed function is `window`.

To get around this, we typically capture `this` into a variable called `self` or `that`. `ko.computed()` provides a second way to capture `this`, and that's by passing it in as the second parameter. That is why your snippet will only work when you include the second `this` parameter.

See the [full docs on Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) (scroll down to Managing "this") for more details.

Comment: Thank you for that, I looked for this snippet on the site and must have passed over it.